# Как реализовать такие же методы у свойства объекта (_.first([1, 2, 3])===_([1, 2, 3]).first()), что и у самого объекта?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

**Отступление**
Хочу лучше понять **js**, то есть пишу свои велосипеды функции, которые уже есть в библиотеке. В качестве примера использую **underscore** https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js

Оформил свой метод **first** для массива, он не закончен, так как начал смотреть тесты и увидел, что метод может вызываться двумя способами.

```
_.first([1, 2, 3])
_([1, 2, 3]).first()
```

Вот реализация, заменил *_* на *u*. Второй вызов выдает ошибку. Понимаю что во втором случае функция инициализации, присваивает **this._wrapped** массив, но нету метода **first**, поэтому мне кажется надо присвоить такие же методы **u**, для **this._wrapped**.

```js
    var u = function(obj) {
        if (obj instanceof u) return u;
        if (!(this instanceof u)) return new u(obj);
        this._wrapped = obj;
    };

    u.first = function(arr, arg) {
        if (arguments.length > 1) {
            return arr.slice(0, arg);
        }
        return arr[0];
    };
    
    console.log(u.first([1,2,3]));
    console.log(u([1,2,3]).first());
```

**Вопрос**
Как реализовать данный вызов `u([1,2,3]).first()` корректно и как работает функция инициализации для **u**. Не совсем понятно это строчка `if (!(this instanceof u)) return new u(obj);`
Используя **js** до **es6**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы второй вызов тоже работал, метод `first` должен быть у результата функции `u`. Сейчас результатом этой функции является новый объект.

Чтобы в этом объекте появился метод, нужно добавить его непосредственно в конструкторе, так же как добавляется свойство `_wrapped`, либо добавить его в прототип.

Чтобы не дублировать код, внутри нового метода можно воспользоваться уже имеющимся методом `first`, например:

```js
var u = function(obj) {
  if (obj instanceof u) return obj;
  if (!(this instanceof u)) return new u(obj);
  this._wrapped = obj;
};

u.first = function(arr, arg) {
  if (arguments.length > 1) {
    return arr.slice(0, arg);
  }
  return arr[0];
};

u.prototype.first = function() {
  return u.first(this._wrapped);
}

console.log(u.first([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(u([1, 2, 3]).first());
```

Comment: А как масштабировать это, если допустим у меня будет 10+ функций? Можно сделать это какой нибудь одной функцией, которая будет перебирать методы, чтоб не писать каждый раз прототип

Comment: @vladislav, если вызов будет стандартный, то можно

Answer (score 0):

на примере `_([1, 2, 3]).first()`:

`_` - это instanceof (как доллор `$` у jQuery), 
`([1, 2, 3])` - метод с возвратом текущего объекта `return this;`
`.first()`  - вызывается с текущего объекта (`this.first()`)